# Some Hexademical numbers get modified when writing to a file

Tags: encoding, clojure, hex, bit-manipulation, hexdump

I'm writing a program which packs hexadecimal strings into bytes and writes them on disk. I expect the hexdump of the file to be same as the hexadecimal things. I'm doing this in Clojure:

```
(defn- hex-char->int
  [hex-char]
  (-> hex-char
      str
      (Integer/parseInt 16)))

(defn- pack
  [hex-1 hex-2]
  (-> hex-1
      (bit-shift-left 4)
      (bit-or hex-2)
      unchecked-char))

(defn- hex-str->packed-bytes
  [hex-str]
  (->> hex-str
       (map hex-char->int)
       (partition 2)
       (mapv (partial apply pack))))

(defn write-bytes
  [bs]
  (with-open [f (io/output-stream "test.txt")]
    (.write f (.getBytes bs))))

(defn test-write
  [hex-str]
  (->> hex-str
       hex-str->packed-bytes
       (apply str)
       write-bytes))
```

This program works well for hex couples from "00" to "7f". I can see the same hex numbers when I hexdump the output file.

But for characters from "80" to "ff", this doesn't work. The hexdump for "80" is "c280" and for "ff" it is "c3bf".

This gets solved if I don't convert to characters and directly write with bytes, so I assume that this is related to encoding.
I even found this: https://superuser.com/questions/1349494/filling-file-with-0xff-gives-c3bf-in-osx

But I want to understand how to solve this in Clojure's context.

Pasting the hexdump of `000f101f202f303f404f505f606f707f808f909fa0afb0bfc0cfd0dfe0eff0ff" for reference:

```
00000000  00 0f 10 1f 20 2f 30 3f  40 4f 50 5f 60 6f 70 7f  |.... /0?@OP_`op.|
00000010  c2 80 c2 8f c2 90 c2 9f  c2 a0 c2 af c2 b0 c2 bf  |................|
00000020  c3 80 c3 8f c3 90 c3 9f  c3 a0 c3 af c3 b0 c3 bf  |................|
00000030
```

Please help me solve this.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You may find the library [`BinF`](https://github.com/helins/binf.cljc) of interest.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, the problem is in encoding.  I'm guessing that the problem is happening when you `(apply str)` in `test-write`.  So, I slightly re-wrote your code as follows:

```clj
user> (defn- hex-char->int
        [hex-char]
        (-> hex-char
            str
            (Integer/parseInt 16)))
#'user/hex-char->int
user> (defn- pack
        [hex-1 hex-2]
        (-> hex-1
            (bit-shift-left 4)
            (bit-or hex-2)))
#'user/pack
user> (defn- hex-str->packed-bytes
        [hex-str]
        (->> hex-str
             (map hex-char->int)
             (partition 2)
             (mapv (partial apply pack))))
#'user/hex-str->packed-bytes
user> (defn write-bytes
        [bs]
        (with-open [f (io/output-stream "test.txt")]
          (.write f bs)))
#'user/write-bytes
user> (defn test-write
        [hex-str]
        (->> hex-str
             hex-str->packed-bytes
             (mapv unchecked-byte)
             (byte-array)
             write-bytes))
#'user/test-write
user> (test-write "000f101f202f303f404f505f606f707f808f909fa0afb0bfc0cfd0dfe0eff0ff")
nil
user>
```

And showing the contents of the resultant file in hex:

```sh
dorabs-imac:example dorab$ od -h test.txt
0000000 0f00 1f10 2f20 3f30 4f40 5f50 6f60 7f70
0000020 8f80 9f90 afa0 bfb0 cfc0 dfd0 efe0 fff0
0000040
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. But I wanted to understand how to make a ascii string out of this.

Comment: It is impossible to make an ASCII string out of 8-bit bytes (where 1 byte is 1 ASCII char).  ASCII is 7-bits (and even out of those, many of the ASCII chars are "non-printable"), so you cannot fit 8-bits of information into 7-bits without loss.  If you want to just print out the byte array, then I'd suggest printing out the hex values. But then you'd have one byte correspond to 2 ASCII (hex) chars.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. Thanks a lot! :)